# Linux: dd and pv -f, How to show only first line?

Tags: linux, bash, printing

I use pv -f in piping like in 'command | pv -f | command2'. pv shows a progress bar like this

```
83.6MB 0:00:03 [27.9MB/s] [  <=>                                               ]
```

When pv exits it shows more information. How can I show only the progress bar?

```
500+0 records in28.3MB/s] [                <=>                                 ]
500+0 records out
524288000 bytes (524 MB) copied, 17.6912 s, 29.6 MB/s
 500MB 0:00:17 [28.3MB/s] [                 <=>                                ]
1024000+0 records in

1024000+0 records out

524288000 bytes (524 MB) copied, 17.6956 s, 29.6 MB/s
```

**Edit:**

My test case was

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=100k count=80000 | pv -f | dd of=/dev/null
```

Comment: I think you are using `dd` to generate data and `dd` is outputting the extraneous stuff, not `pv` - try `dd if=/dev/zero bs=100k count=80000 2> /dev/null | pv -f | dd of=/dev/null 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize that the printing was caused by dd.

Comment: FYI, you can also run `dd status=none` to suppress its printing to stderr, while still allowing it to output errors.

Comment: Interesting. `dd if=/dev/zero bs=100k count=80000 | head -n $size` if I remove the count parameter final statistics are not shown. There is a case where I would need those final statistics and I can't use the count parameter.